# How to intercept request for specific file type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

Our application is a Java/Spring3/Spring MVC/Hibernate based app.

We have some resources that are stored in various different places on the server machine. The locations are stored in the database. Basically when the web application requests a file from a uri like `/<our-app>/page/file.kml` when need to intercept this call, ignore the requested uri, lookup the actual location of the file and return that as the response.

In our `servlet-context.xml` we have some interceptors;

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/page/**" />
        <beans:bean class="com.ourapp.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/page/*.kml" />
        <beans:bean class="com.ourapp.KmlInterceptor" />
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

The first intercept is for our authentication and works great. Basically makes sure the user is logged in for ANY request.

The second interceptor is what we've setup to try and intercept requests to KML files from geoXML3. The interceptor doesn't seem to be firing? (ie the KmlInterceptor.preHandle doesn't get called?).

Are we doing the correct mapping there?

Is this the way to intercept requests for specific file types and return the actual file retrieved from somewhere else?

Comment: Is the path of the files `/pages/something.kml`, or are there more sub directories? If yes, maybe trying with `/page/**/*.kml` will do.

Comment: Well thats the point, there is no file at /page/something.kml. We want to catch the request to that uri, find the file elsewhere and return it on the response. ie never let the web app actually look for a file at /page/something.kml

Comment: Yep, I understood that. I was asking because the expression could be wrong if the fake document was at `/pages/adirectory/file.kml`

Comment: hmm no, its definitely requesting /page/file.kml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In actual fact, we moved away from trying to use an interceptor and just used a normal `@RequestMapping` annotation instead;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page/location/*.kml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getKMLFile(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    try {
        // Getting the filename (ie splitting off the /page/location/ part)
        String uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        String[] parts = uri.split("/");
        String alais = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // Our app specific code finding the file from the db location 
        Resource resource = resourceService.getResourceByAlias(alais);
        File file = resource.getAbsFile();

        // Putting the file onto the httpResponse 
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(is, httpResponse.getOutputStream());
        httpResponse.flushBuffer();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```